# automatic serialization of the serial number based on two parameters c#

Tags: c#, sorting, datetime, object, serial-number

I need help with serial numbers.
I need a serial number to be generated based on the department and the month.
departmentyearmonth_serial number

KL2103_01,
KM2103_01,
KL2103_02...

```
textBox1.Text = textBox2.Text + dtim.ToString("yyMM") + serial number;
```

What should the cod for serial number look like?

Thank you for your help?

Comment: Where does the serial number come from? Should it be generated from somewhere else and overtaken into your system or do you want to generate it by yourself, e.g. through incrementing by 1?

Comment: I get the department from a table in SQL server.
I need to make the serial number denominated depending on the department and the month. To start the new month with numbering from 1 for all departments. KL2103_02,KM2103_12, KL2104_01,KM2104_01

Answer (score 0):

```
public string GetSerialNumber(string department, string serialNumber)
{
    return department + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMM") + "_" + serialNumber;
}
```

then when you call it:

```
textBox1.Text = GetSerialNumber("KL",01);
```

you could also create the possible departments as enums to avoid typos and depending on your serial number generation access it in the GetSerialNumber method and therefore eliminate the second method parameter

**edit**: You don't know how to generate the number part? you could keep the last used number in a variable and increment it. if you need a separate number for each department you could use an int array together with the enum I already suggested:

```
enum Department
{
  KL,
  KM
}

int[] ids = new int[]{0,0}
```

then you can change the method to:

```
public string GetSerialNumber(Department department)
{
    return department.ToString() + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMM") + "_" + (++ids[department]);
}
```

to get persistent serail numbers after restarting the application you have to save and load the values somewhere

Comment: I get the department from a table in SQL server.
I need to make the serial number denominated depending on the department and the month. To start the new month with numbering from 1 for all departments. KL2103_02,KM2103_12, KL2104_01,KM2104_01

Answer (score 0):

Global in your app:
Make a class/struct with department string and serial index (int) as member.
Make a list of these classes/structs.
Add a variable for the current month.
All these variables are to be stored somewhere at disk/net (depending if it's running at only one computer or at different of the network).

If you have to create a number first check if the current month has changed by comparing with the variable. If it has changed create a new list, store the new month at the variable. Then search the department string in the list. If it's not found add a new entry to the list with the given department string and 1 as index. If it was found increase the index. Then create the string like petule.08 told it with the function GetSerialNumber and the new index.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help i finally figured it out myself.

1. Using DataRow, I searched for all records similar to the pattern ("select" function)
2. using "if" under the condition of finding the pattern is counted using "count" and increased by one.
3. if the pattern is not found, it is written automatically 1